# Convert a cURL [GET] request to Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I have this curl request:

```
curl -k -H"Authorization: Bearer 905290532905902390523905krai20" https://example.com/something?limit=1
```

`Bearer` is a token_type (`$token_type`).
The long string is an access token (`$access_token`)

How can I convert this to a Guzzle request? I already converted another curl POST request to Guzzle, but this isn't the same deal.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you understand what the `-H` option to `curl` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've never used this library in my life, but after a quick look at [the documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#headers), it seems this should work:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://example.com/something?limit=1'
]);
$client->request('GET', '/get', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer 905290532905902390523905krai20',
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Silly of me. Thanks!

Comment: @miken  Please help me to convert this CURL request to guzzle 
curl -X POST \
  'http://test.eventstravel.eu/webservice/v1/orders/create?token=<<YOUR_TOKEN>>&language=EN' \
  -d '{"remarks": "remarks","products":[{"sku":"2517000000025","amount":1,"company":"Moddix","firstname":"Helge","lastname":"van Scherpenzeel","phonenumber":71820345,"email":"helge_et@moddix.nl","booking_reference":"#12345","checkin_date":"","street":"Bargelaan","housenumber":26,"zipcode":"2333CT","city":"Leiden","country":"Nederland","passport_name":"Barry Gonzalez","date_of_birth":"01-04-1979","nationality":"Multi"}]}'

Comment: current code is 
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [ 'form_params' => ['remarks' => 'remarks','products' => [ 'sku' => '25170','amount' => 1, 'company' => 'Novaturesol','firstname' => 'Aw','lastname' => 'Zul','phonenumber' =>  323,'booking_reference' => '#11223','email' => 'test@test.nl', 'checkin_date' => '',  'street' => 'Ton',  'housenumber' => 'Test 1',  'zipcode' => '54700',  'city' => 'Leid','country' => 'Nedrl','passport_name' => 'Barry', 'date_of_birth' => '1993-01-12', 'nationality' => 'Mlti'] ]])->getBody()->getContents();